# Synchronize uniform buffer updates in Metal

Tags: synchronization, metal

Let's assume I have the following code (simplified):

```
id<MTLBuffer> uniforms = ...;
MTLRenderCommandEncoder encoder = ...;

[uniforms contents] = some_data;
[encoder setVertexbuffer: uniforms ...];

DrawSomethingWithShader("myshader");

[uniforms contents] = some_other_data;    // WRONG! overwrites previous draw call's uniforms
[encoder setVertexbuffer: uniforms ...];

DrawSomethingElseWithShader("myshader");
```

In Vulkan there is a mechanism for this called *vkCmdPipelineBarrier()*. However, I couldn't find anything similar in Metal (*MTLFence* is a candidate, but seemingly it is used for other kinds of things).

So my question is how to synchronize this buffer update?

*(ps.: my current idea is to track modifications to the buffer and copy the "second uniform data" to another location, but it would be rather complicated to implement in a robust way)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the uniform data for every draw call encoded into a command buffer is accessible not merely until you end encoding, but until the command buffer itself completes.

This means you should add an offset to the contents pointer of the buffer and write the uniform data for consecutive draw calls in consecutive portions of the buffer. You should then not write to the region of the buffer corresponding to this frame until it completes.

Since you will likely get a callback to draw the next frame before the frame you are encoding completes, you should use a pool of buffers and cycle among them, controlling access with a counting semaphore. This recommendation is detailed in the [Metal Best Practices Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/MTLBestPracticesGuide/TripleBuffering.html).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of...Thanks anyway.

(ps.: I leave the question open tho for a few more days)